# Changing the src of a video with Asp.Net/VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html5-video

I'm just a beginner with all this and want to display a video on my website which can be changed from the VB code. I found a website which said to use the video tag. The code has 2 lines which add backup codecs by the look of it so I'd like to keep that if possible. I added ID="videoToPlay" and  runat="server" to it in hope I could simply change the file to play with videoToPlay.src="" but no luck. Any help appreciated.

```
<video ID="videoToPlay" runat="server" src="catalog/videos/636951035994809759_20190602_201932.mp4" style="width:90%; height:315" controls>
    <source src="devstories.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="devstories.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>


Dim videoToPlay As Video
videoToPlay.src="catalog/videos/" & session("video")
```

I am getting error.. 
Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'source' is not a member of 'video'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the source from the Video ID.

```
    <video ID="videoToPlay" runat="server" style="width:90%; height:315" controls>
        <source src="devstories.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
        <source src="devstories.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    </video>


Dim videoToPlay As Video
videoToPlay.src="catalog/videos/" & session("video")
```

Comment: Hi and thanks.. However, I'm still getting the same error when I remove the source